# Help understanding this problem

Tags: general-topology

In an exercise I am asked to prove the following:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a discrete topological space. Prove that $(X,\tau)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\Bbb R$ if and only if $X$ is countable.

The problem is that I'm not sure what they are asking me to prove.
What do they mean by "a subspace of $\Bbb R$"? Do they want me to prove that $X$ is homeomorphic to every subspace of $\Bbb R$? Or do I need to prove that there exists a subspace of $\Bbb R$ which is homeomorphic to $X$ if and only if $X$ is countable?
What are they asking me to prove?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: "$(X, \tau)$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$" means : "there exists a subspace $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $S$ endowed with the natural topology is homeomorphic to $(X, \tau)$".

Comment: To add to what the others have said: I would dismiss the first interpretation already based on it not making sense in the first place. Whatever $X$ is, it cannot possibly be homeomorphic to *all* subspaces of $\mathbb R$ because then all subspaces of $\mathbb R$ would be homeomorphic to each other. (?!)

Comment: Do you want to forget about the question once you know what it means or you also want to know how to prove it? Some guys are saying I have committed a  crime by providing  a proof.  Please tell me what your stand is.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy intact I did not asked for a proof and wanted do prove it myself, just wanted help with the interpretation, but I can just ignore and don't look at you proof until I'm finished with my own, so I don't see any harm in showing your proof

Comment: Thank you for that response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do they want me to prove that $X$ is homeomorphic to every subspace of $\Bbb R$?

No, that has no chance of happening. Both $\{0\}$ and $\{0,1\}$ are discrete subspaces of $\Bbb R$ but can both of them be homeomorphic to some fixed $X$?

> Or do I need to prove that there exists a subspace of $\Bbb R$ which is homeomorphic to $X$ if and only if $X$ is countable?

Exactly.